Centering an image in after or before pseudo element
I'm STUCK on this! I am trying to add an image of 5 stars to a testimonial slider on Shopify. I've been playing in the CSS and have scaled to the size I've wanted the image to be, adjusted spacing, etc — but I can't get this to be centered perfectly. My current code is:
.prose::after {
    content: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0780/3689/3975/files/5_star_png.png?v=1713317867');
 display: flex;
  width:10px;
  height:20px;
   transform: scale(.12);
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
      justify-items: center;
  align-content:start;
  }


Image below as well! Any tips super appreciated.

Tried tweaking the display, changing content to background, etc. I'm self taught but new to this, help!!

Without seeing your HTML, this centers the stars within the prose div.
justify-items should be justify-content and the width should most likely be 100%, otherwise you're trying to center the stars within 10px
I also removed the transform: scale(.12) since that would make your element very small.


.prose::after {
  content: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0780/3689/3975/files/5_star_png.png?v=1713317867');
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  justify-content: center;
}
<div class="prose">

</div>




Thank you so much, SUPER helpful! The transform part actually helps shrink it down to the size needed - this centers the stars beautifully, but messes up the rest of the block/breaks the code a little. I'm sure I'll figure it out :) thanks so much again!

Any tips on how to fix this issue on mobile? I've added the max-width code from the rest of the element but on mobile it cuts things off. No clue how to insert a screenshot but here's a link to what happens: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0780/3689/3975/files/Screenshot_2024-04-17_at_9.10.43_PM.png?v=1713402655 — no worries if you aren't sure :)

Without seeing the actual code, it would be difficult to help out. There could be many reasons why things are not responding correctly on mobile.
